# Hard Reset an input field using .reset(); after ajax success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can i hard reset an input field using

```
$(".editauthorl")[0].reset();
```

instead of

```
$(".editauthorl").val('');
```

Is it possible?

I cannot use

```
$("form1")[0].reset();
```

because it will clear the whole form and I am using serialize in inserting data which can clear my unique identifier in the process. Any suggestions would be great! Thanks

Comment: If you're going to reset individual fields, you can simply use `.val('')`

Comment: @Phiter The problem is when use .val( ' ' ) in clearing fields my validator throws the wrong message. It seems that .val( ' ' ) is not doing a hard reset on the input field.

Comment: This will change the current input value to an empty string.  You should be able to reset the form and get the id again to the id field